# Display form errors if the checkValidity() method returns false

Tags: javascript, html, validation

**Short version of the question**

Is there a way to trigger the native browser form validation error feedback with Javascript?

**Detailed version of the question**

When trying to submit a form that has a required input field that has not been filled by the user, modern browsers handle the validation automatically, and **display an error for the input field where an error has been found**.

Each browser handles this in an own way, but to get an idea, here is how Edge is doing it today:

[image]

I want to achieve the same native validation feedback but without using the submit event.

According to the documentation for [HTMLSelectElement.checkValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity), I am able to know if the form does validate or not.

I could use this `true/false` information and handle the visual feedback by writing custom code, but I wonder if there is a way to trigger the native browser error feedback, so I can save time.

**Did I try something?**

Yes, I tried using a common submit button and using prevent default event to do what I like (and it works), but I want to know if there is a straight way to achieve this, something like `HTMLSelectElement.displayErrors()` would be logic.

**UPDATE**

In fact, the method does exist, it's called [HTMLFormElement.reportValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by calling `reportValidity()` on the given input field.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  e.target.reportValidity();
});
```

```html
<input type="email" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Emil's answer, I made it work the way I wanted.

I am leaving it here for further readers but accepting Emil's answer since that was the key part.

According to the docs, you can run the [checkValidity() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) on the form itself, not necessarily on the child input.

```
function processForm(){

    // Early return form processing if validation errors where found
    if(!document.getElementById('form-id').checkValidity()){
        document.getElementById('form-id').reportValidity();
        return false;
    }

    // Okay, all cool, do stuff...

}
```